# How to configure Apache Buildr to use the same directories as Maven?

Tags: maven-2, buildr

By default, Buildr produces output in slightly different places than Maven's default.  For example, it puts test classes in `target/test/classes` instead of `target/test-classes`, reports in `reports/` instead of `target/surefire-reports`, and JavaDoc into `target/doc` instead of `target/site/apidocs`.

Is there a list of all such differences, and how to configure Buildr to use the same output directories as Maven?  Would that even be safe to do, e.g., if there is a parallel Maven project that is being migrated from provided that the two never run simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [configure buildr to use different directories from the defaults](http://buildr.apache.org/extending.html#layouts).

It doesn't seem to me temporarily having both maven and buildr builds in the same directories would cause any problems, but I've never tried it myself.  Certainly any problems would be resolvable with a clean build.

Comment: But there's no sample Maven Layout included?

Comment: Buildr self-consciously adopts the maven layout for source.  I don't think there's an official reason why it doesn't mimic the target layout (except for things like tests, where, since it doesn't use surefire, calling the output `surefire-reports` would be misleading).  AFAIK, there's no built-in support to copy maven's output structure.